# CocoaLumberjack Swift framework

Tags: swift, swift3, cocoalumberjack

I'm currently writing some swift libraries to be included in an App that uses CocoaLumberjack to log.
So initially I've added CocoaLumberjack as a dependency to all of them and it works quite well.

Then I've seen [this ticket](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/694) where they say, that you should not add it as a dependency, but use if it is there.

Despite that I've already seen some projects on GitHub where they do exactly that in Objective-C, I haven't seen it yet in Swift.

Can somebody point me to a sample project or help me to find the right direction to take

THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your should add `CocoaLumberjack/Swift` as a dependency if your library uses it as a logger.

But your library code should not add any loggers (`DDTTYLogger`, `DDFileLogger`, etc.) to avoid log duplication.

Adding loggers should be done in final application that uses your library.

For library itself it could be test bundle with tests:

```
class YourKitTests: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        DDLog.add(DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance(), with: .verbose)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you "Adding loggers should be done in final application that uses your library.", then why don't you add CocoaLumberjack/Swift as a dependency in the final application only?